# point on a object in THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have loaded an .obj file. I would like to put a point on the brain, and that it does not change when the camera moves, that it is always at the same point as in this image.

[image]

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
        /* */
loader.load( 'freesurf.OBJ', function ( object ) {

 brain = object;
 object.position.y = 0;
 scene.add( object );

} );
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/iAr4Rl4Ohlq6bQIqdbJ6?p=preview

Comment: Would you like to have fix point on the brain object which rotate, or would you like to have fix point on the screen?

Comment: @hsd a fixed point in the brain

Comment: Take a look at the [decals](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals) technique.

Comment: @prisoner849 how can do it with a custom form, as a circle?

Comment: @yavg if you look in the [source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/fdefb19bdd8dbb7d549fa701b1324bfcd9ff1933/examples/webgl_decals.html#L60), then you'll see how they made the splash. So, for a circle, you can use your own texture with the picture of it.

Comment: @prisoner849 I do not want to use any texture, just a sphere basically, will it work?

Comment: @yavg so you can rely on the answer from `hsd`. There are several ways to achieve what you describe as the result. And the way with a regular sphere is not what you want, I think. But creativity is up to you anyway :)

Comment: @prisoner849 No, I hope you understand me. I want an effect like the image, maybe doing what you propose, but with a sphere can work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155927/discussion-between-prisoner849-and-yavg).

Comment: @prisoner849 https://plnkr.co/edit/fxKoMsnAPPDUDK3qUGsh?p=preview  can you look in the line 98. I am trying decal geometry with a circle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537075/paint-specific-regions-of-a-model-in-three-js

Different question but seems to be expecting the same answer.

Comment: @pailhead no, they are different. one is to put one point on the object, the other paint regions, are similar. I apologize I will delete the second

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution base on `SphereGeometry`
https://plnkr.co/edit/Y15PFd2Fietq5cjQLJjw?p=preview

I changed this part of code.

```
    var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'blue',transparent:true,opacity:0.5,

      depthFunc:THREE.LessDepth,side:THREE.FrontSide,})

      var sphr = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1,16,16),mat);
      sphr.position.set(1.3, 1.3, 0 );
      brain.add(sphr);


    } );
```

This is not perfect solution but working with approach of ball. 
To make this better you should play with pixel shader or create geometry base on the background object.

Project which can solve your problem is
https://github.com/tomtung/chameleon.js

Comment: thanks..is almost what I need !. but, I want the circle to have an effect somewhat like a spot of light illuminating a part of the brain.

Comment: @yavg please take a look on project https://github.com/tomtung/chameleon.js